# About sizeof of a class member function pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sizeof, member

Let's say we have a class A

```
class A;
```

and these typedefs

```
typedef void (A::*a_func_ptr)(void);
typedef void (*func_ptr)(void);
```

My question is why sizeof(a_func_ptr) returns 16, while sizeof(func_ptr) returns 4 (as for any pointer on x86 system)?

For instance

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a = sizeof(a_func_ptr);
  int b = sizeof(func_ptr);
}
```

Comment: It's [because of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13875868/335858).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is why sizeof(a_func_ptr) returns 16, while sizeof(func_ptr) returns 4 (as for any pointer on x86 system)?

Because pointer-to-members are implemented differently. They're *not* pointers under the hood. Some compilers, such as MSVC, implement them as `struct` with more than one members in it.

Read this interesting article:

- [Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713)

Note that in some compilers, they might have same size. The bottomline is:  they're compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl; }
    void bar(){ std::cout << "A::bar" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
     void foo(){  std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl; }
     void bar(){ std::cout << "B::bar" << std::endl; }
};

typedef void (A::*a_func_ptr)(void);

int main() {
   a_func_ptr f = &A::foo;
   a_func_ptr g = &A::bar;
   B b;
   A a;
   (b.*f)();
   (b.*g)();
   (a.*f)();
   (a.*g)();
}
```

Output:

```
B::foo
A::bar
A::foo
A::bar
```

Both member pointers are of the same type, yet both correctly routed the call in every cases.

Somehow, the generated programme *must know* when a pointer to method is actually a **simple method** or a **virtual one**. Thus the runtime representation of a method pointer has to include more information to handle the second case.

<sub>Remark: the size seems to be implementation dependent (I get `8` on my system).</sub>

Comment: no alias of " a_func_ptr" - why you pass not worked code?

Answer (score 2):

Pointer-to-member function of class doesn't hold the "exact address" like a regular pointer does. It stores more information than regular function pointer.

So when you use `sizeof` to measure the size of a pointer-to-member function of a class, you should not expect that it will be same size as a regular function pointer.

Comment: A method, contrary to a data member, is shared by all instances of the class so it can't have an offset in the class layout. Or did you mean that the pointer-to-member must also store, at the very least, the `this` pointer in addition to the method's address?

Comment: @syam what I was trying to say that pointer to member function stores more information than regular function pointers. That imagine part may be misleading, I will remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers to member functions may be a data structure as pointed out in the C++ FAQ [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr.html). Also [Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713) offers an example of how it is implemented for Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

> Although function pointers in C and C++ can be implemented as simple
>   addresses, so that typically sizeof(Fx)==sizeof(void *), member
>   pointers in C++ are often implemented as "fat pointers", typically two
>   or three times the size of a simple function pointer, in order to deal
>   with virtual inheritance.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)

This [SO answer offers additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875786/pointers-to-members-representations/13875868#13875868).

Answer (score 0):

A related question is discussed here:
[Is the sizeof(some pointer) always equal to four?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four)

See:
[Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx)
for further Information.