# Function pointer conversion using union

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010

```
typedef void (*callable_function)(double);
void call_function(callable_function func)
{
    func(3.0);
}

class Foo;

union converter {
    callable_function func;
    void (Foo::*foo_func)(void);
};

class Foo {
private:
    double d;
public:
    Foo(void) : d(0.0)
    {
        converter c;
        c.foo_func = &Foo::set_double;
        call_function(c.func);//I know i can call the function directly, but that is not what i want to achieve
    }

    void set_double(double value)
    {
        d = value;
    }
};

void main(void)
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

When trying to execute the code above, i get a heap corruption error in the line:
`d = value;`.
Probably because the function being called is the class function, not the member function.
But if i try to change this line: `c.foo_func = &Foo::set_double;` to `c.foo_func = &this->set_double;`, i get this compiler error:
`error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression`

**Question #1:** Is there any way to convert the pointer(casting maybe) from `void(Foo::*)(void)` to `void()(void)` or to fix the compiler error?

Comment: Why are you writing code that is incomprehensible? Even the compiler has problems.

Comment: Then how can i make it more comprehensible to you?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? To call a member function, you need an object of that class. What is `d` when you call `set_double` without an instance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is undefined behavior (since you're doing it through a union).

Comment: DyP, I make an instance of Foo in the main function.

Comment: for a start main should return an integer. Also have you heard of interfaces? Besides why not have a real user name?

Comment: @user2565020 And how shall `call_function` know about this instance? A call via a member function pointer looks like this: `(my_instance.*my_mem_fun_ptr)(arguments);` so the instance is known. But in your example, you call the member function *as if it was a free function* (technically, the access to the uninitialized member of the union already invokes undefined behaviour, but this is where things really go wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pointer to "free" function and pointer to member function in C++ have different sizes. 
That means you *technically can* cast pointer to free function to void* ptr as usually they have the same size but you cannot cast member function pointer to void* or other free function - you will get what you've got.

Check this: [Pointers to members representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875786/pointers-to-members-representations)