# How to create a typedef of the current function, but remove one argument and change the calling convention?

Tags: c++, hook, calling-convention

I want to know if there is a way of creating a typedef the currently executing function, but remove the 2nd argument change its calling convention to __thiscall? At the moment I'm doing this:

```
// Some other part of the application code will set this value to something valid
void* real_function_addr = (void*)0xdeadbeef;

int __fastcall a_hooked_thiscall_function( void *thisPtr, void* not_used, int param)
{
    // Cast a known address to the same signature as the current function, but change
    // the calling convention to __thiscall and remove the not_used param.
    typedef int (__thiscall* func_ptr_t)(void *thisPtr, int param);
    func_ptr_t real_function_addr_typed = reinterpret_cast< func_ptr_t >( real_function_addr );
    return real_function_addr_typed( thisPtr, param );
}
```

It would be better if there was some macro hackery or template I could use to do something like:

```
// Some other part of the application code will set this value to something valid
void* real_function_addr = (void*)0xdeadbeef;

int __fastcall a_hooked_thiscall_function( void *thisPtr, void* not_used, int param)
{
    // Where MAKE_THISCALL somehow fixes up real_function_addr to be a function pointer of type a_hooked_thiscall_function but with __fastcall replaced with __thiscall and the 2nd argument removed
    return MAKE_THISCALL(a_hooked_thiscall_function, real_function_addr)( thisPtr, param );
}
```

Comment: For starters, fix the type of `real_function_addr`.  The language frowns on casting between object (data) pointers and function pointers anyway, and `void*` falls into the "compatible with object pointers" category.

Comment: @BenVoigt but if he's in a POSIX environment it is well defined.

Comment: May I ask what exactly the question is? Does what you're doing work?

Comment: It works because this is used for hooking a C++ member function, but since I need to hook a lot of them I want a way to cutdown the boiler plate __stdcall to __thiscall conversion code

Comment: Write a macro that encapsulates those 3 lines of code? Note that your code only *works* in simple cases. Once you throw virtual functions/multiple inheritance/virtual inheritance into the mix, there's [little chance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875868/241631) you can stuff a member function pointer into a `void *` and get away with it.