# pointer to member function of incomplete type

Tags: c++, incomplete-type, pointer-to-member

I don't understand why adding a forward declaration for a class changes a size of its pointer to member type

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //struct CL;
    //cout<<sizeof(int (CL::*)())<<endl; 
    struct CL{};
    cout<<sizeof(int (CL::*)())<<endl;
}
```

output VS2013:
4

But if I uncomment the first two lines in main(), then the output is different:
16
16

So, only a simple adding a forward declaration before a definition of struct CL increases a size of a pointer to member of CL. Why? I know that a size of member function pointer depends by structure of a type (e.g. virtual functions and base classes may increase it), but why can the sizeof operator be applied to a pointer to member of an incomplete type? Or it can't? I have not found it in the Standard

Comment: `struct CL{}` is definitely a local class in the function. Not sure about `struct CL;` Anyways, it looks like a bug of msvc

Comment: @DieterLücking `struct CL;` is a forward-declaration of a local class in this case, see [basic.scope.pdecl]p7.1

Comment: See also: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9cfa5c4-d90b-4c33-89b1-9366e5fbae74/strange-error-while-casting-pointers-to-member-functions?forum=vclanguage (via http://stackoverflow.com/a/13881429/ )

Comment: @dyp Is that another reason to hate msvc?

Comment: @DieterLücking It is another reason to set it up properly ;) Just like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++??` in g++, you need to deactivate language extensions in cl, possibly deactivate comdat folding, and force it to use the same size for all member pointers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MSVC compiler uses different sizes for pointers to member functions as an optimization. This optimization violates the Standard. Kudos to [Igor Tandetnik](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/igor%20tandetnik/) mentioning `reinterpret_cast` in [a MSDN form post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9cfa5c4-d90b-4c33-89b1-9366e5fbae74/strange-error-while-casting-pointers-to-member-functions?forum=vclanguage), [expr.reinterpret.cast]p10

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `X` of type `T1`” can be
> explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to
> member of `Y` of type `T2`” if `T1` and `T2` are both function types
> or both object types. The null member pointer value is converted to
> the null member pointer value of the destination type. The result of
> this conversion is unspecified, except in the following cases:
>
> - converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer to member function type and back to its original
>   type yields the original pointer to member value.

So there's a roundtrip guarantee, this effectively forces conforming implementations to use the same size for all pointer to member function types.

---

The MSVC optimization is performed if the [`/vmb` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yad46a6z.aspx) is set. For the case of single inheritance, the optimised pointer to member function requires only a `void*`-sized storage, see [The Old New Thing: Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713).

If you only forward-declare the type `CL` and then form a pointer-to-member function, the optimization hopefully is deactivated (I could not find any documentation on that, unfortunately). Otherwise, you might get inconsistent sizes before and after the definition of `CL`.

By the way, you can get inconsistent sizes for enumerations in VS2010, if you forward-declare them *without specifying an underlying type* and later explicitly define the underlying type for the definition of the enum. This works only with language extensions activated.

Comment: There is also a [pragma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83cch5a6.aspx) which claims that you need to define the class before you can form a pointer-to-member to it. But that's not true at least in VS2013..