# Can i cast method pointer to long(int, size_t)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, methods, clang++

My problem is i need to represent a pointer to class's method like integer number. So it's not problem with functions, for example `void (*func)()` easy cast to number, but when i trying to cast `void (&SomeClass::SomeMethod)` to integer with any ways compiles says it's impossible

> C-style cast from 'void(ForthInterpreter::*)()' to long is not alowed

I tried `(size_t)&ForthInterpreter::CodeFLiteral`, `static_cast<size_t>(&ForthInterpreter::CodeFLiteral)` but i got the same errors. Should to suppose there is a principal differense between pointer to function and method but what is it? And how can i cast it succesfully?
I use clang++ with C++11 version.

Comment: what do you want to do with the integer ?

Comment: A "pointer-to-member" is only a pointer in an abstract sense; it represents an indirection. It is not a *pointer* except by name.

Comment: "*i need to represent a pointer to class's method like integer number*" - why? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is likely to be better solutions.

Comment: note: `long` is not able to safely roundtrip a pointer only `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t` are able to. However I'm not sure if that extends to pointer to member too. Regardless `long` will cause issues.

Comment: _"suppose there is a principal differense between pointer to function and method but what is it?"_  A pointer to member function can be `virtual`, in which case it is pointing to an unspecified number of functions until it is bound to a specific object instance.  The standard does not specify how this must be implemented and certainly does not promise that the implementation does not exceed the size of a `long`.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you were trying to achieve, but you might consider: [std::mem_fn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer-to-member is not just a simple pointer, it is much more complex.  Depending on compiler implementation, it could be 2 pointers, one to the object and one to the method.  Or it could be an object pointer and an offset into a method table.  And so on.

As such, a pointer-to-member simply cannot be stored as-is in an integer, like you are attempting to do.  So you need to find another solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve by storing a pointer inside an integer.

Comment: IIRC MSVC used to use pointer to member that could be 16bytes on x86 (not x64) systems. [and found a related source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875868)

Answer (score 2):

> for example void (*func)() easy cast to number

No it's not, it just looks like it on your specific machine. There are systems where a pointer is represented as two internal values, for example read about [far pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer).

Not to mention the 64-bit problems you're inviting, `long` is different types in x64 on `gcc` and `cl` for example, two very main-stream compilers.

> when i trying to cast void (&SomeClass::SomeMethod) to integer with any ways compiles says it's impossible

Absolutely, because not only a class member pointer has the same problem as above, but it absolutely requires a pointer to the object instance itself (usually passed as a register, and again usually `ecx` or `rcx`). There's no way you can represent that in a more portable way than a pointer to the correct type.

> i need to represent a pointer to class's method like integer number

No you don't, you just *want* to. There's a difference there. The solution is to adapt to what is possible instead.

Comment: I need it, because i got some code, which operates with pointers to functions and i have to rewrite some functions to methods. And problem comes in part of code, which have been casting function's pointers, because now all of these functions comes like methods