# How to implemented comparison/less operator for member method pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, operator-overloading, function-pointers

From my reading, I understand that it is possible to compare some pointer types in C++ using either `operator<` or `std::less`.  This is useful if, for example, a pointer is used as a key for a `std::map` or in a sorted list.

However, I am having difficulty comparing pointer's to member functions.

Here is some example code that **does not compile** due to `operator<` not being found (just focus on the comparison of the pointers).

```
#include <map>

class Base
{
public:
    //...
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    bool a(int v) { return v < 10; }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    bool b(int v) { return v > 10; }
};

using Fn = bool (Base::*)(int);

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    Fn fn1 = static_cast<Fn>(&A::a);
    Fn fn2 = static_cast<Fn>(&B::b);

    std::map<Fn, Base*> functions;
    functions[fn1] = &a;
    functions[fn2] = &b;

    return 0;
};
```

I was able to get this to compile (albeit with warnings) be implementing `operator<` using `reinterpret_cast` to `void*`.  This forces the compiler to do what I want (since all pointers are implemented the same way to my knowledge), but I'm aware that it's a very ugly solution.

Is there a way to compare these pointers?

For those who want to know the real problem context, this is used in a C++ implementation of statecharts as proposed in this book: https://www.state-machine.com/doc/PSiCC.pdf.  The map is used to store the "history" for each state.  Since states are implemented as member methods, the map creates a "mapping" between a state (the key) and its history (the value).

Comment: `std::map` is *ordered*. And it's ordered by the *key*. The ordering is done using the `<` operator. If the key doesn't have any `<` operation or overload, then it can't be used as a key. You might be able to bypass it by using `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: But please [edit] your question to tell us the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need a map with non-static member function pointers as key? How would that solve your actual and underlying problem? Perhaps there are other solutions? Right now, your question unfortunately is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But my point is, a pointer is a pointer (i.e., a memory address).  Thus, at least at the lowest level, they should all be comparable/sortable (at least between pointers of the type if you want to be a bit safer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875786/pointers-to-members-representations - not all pointers are "just pointers"

Comment: @Mat Very helpful, thank you.  My question still remains though, even if member function pointers are special, they are still something, and I am wondering if it is possible to compare those somethings (as long as they are the same type).

Comment: @PatrickWright -- re: "a pointer is a pointer" -- yes, but a pointer-to-member-function is not a pointer. Don't program by pun.

Comment: Pointers to member functions are something, yes. They're just not an ordered something and there is no sensible definition of ordering for them.

Comment: The fun thing about C++ is it's complicated and it supports a lot of hardware. A lot of a stuff that seems like it would be a common sense slam dunk cannot be specified in such a way that the results are guaranteed on all targets.

Comment: Handy reading for folks who find this in the future: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Pointer_comparison_operators

Comment: @StephenM.Webb What really confuses me is, how come you are allowed to compare member function pointers for equality?  If you can figure out if two things are the same, shouldn't there be *some* way to order them (even if you have to invent some arbitrary way to do so)?  For example, "colors" don't really have an order, but I could order them by wavelength, my personal preference, etc...

Comment: FYI, this page also has some good information on member function pointers: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object and function pointers are expected to be just numbers. They're typed, and the builtin comparison operators don't impose a strict total order. But since these things are just numbers, a strict total order is expected to exist, and you can access it via `std::less` and its ilk.

Member pointers are not just numbers; they are not just an address. As such, there is no strict total order required for them. Nor can you manufacture one. Two member pointers could have the same value representation (ie: separate bits) even if they are "pointing" to different functions, depending on how they get implemented.

Your `reinterpret_cast` solution is unreliable.